# Can I overcome Google API auth barrier by using single account?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm building a showcase prototype of a WebApp and I'm planning to use Google Calendar API. We will deploy to GAE.

The problem is all data to be sent to a service, such as the calendar API, needs authorization.

My plan for the prototype is to use authentication ClientLogin on my GAE backend. I'll create a user account on Google Business (free version) which I will use to authorize the API transactions.

I'll create many calendars for the user and send data through the authorized user.

Does anyone know something about avoiding this approach?

Thx!

Comment: So users will only access calendars through your android app?

Comment: It is to hold events on shared calendars. I want to control user events in a single or a few calendars. It will be for demo purpose, I don't want to remake Calendar backend for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your AppEngine app to manage calendar entries for all your users, you should use the [app identity API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/) to identify the app to Google Calendar. The app gets a single address, in the form appname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, which can own the calendar and invite the users to events.

Comment: Didn't know about this. I found this on David Chandler's blog (http://goo.gl/bY8hj). Thx!